# Removing Eclipse/JUnit call stack cut-off

Tags: eclipse, junit, callstack

When I run a JUnit that fails in Eclipse I sometimes get the call stack similar to this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.a.b.c.d.e.MyTest.method(MyTest.java:73)
    at com.a.b.c.d.e.MyTest.testConvertRawInternalAtomAllowCompound(MyTest.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    .... 57 more
```

How can I remove the cut-off? I'd like to see the whole call stack. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this is at least a bit useful.

From **[here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/426029/vc/Eclipse-showing-incomplete-stack-trace)** :

> The "... xx more" message usually occurs when there are nested
>   exceptions. When that happens, the full stack trace is printed for the
>   first exception stack trace, but for each "caused by" exception stack
>   trace, only the portions of the stack trace that do not duplicate the
>   first (or prior) stack trace are printed. Look at the line before "...
>   xx more" - you should be able to go to the first stack trace and
>   locate the same line in that stack trace - and there should be xx more
>   lines in that first stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that you have added "Type Filters" to your company related packages?

Comment: Not that I know of, how can I check?